# Using MS Word 2010 spell check functionality hidden behind

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word, spell-checking

I'm using MS Word's spell checking functionality in my C# WinForms application.
This works fine with Office 2007, but for machines with Office 2010 installed I have some trouble. The word application opens behind my current application window and the application would seems frozen. Using alt+tab I can get to the word app, but this is not user friendly.

```
Word._Application app = new Word.Application();

//int errors = 0;
if (p_TextToCheck != "")
{
    app.Visible = false;

    // Setting these variables is comparable to passing null to the function.
    // This is necessary because the C# null cannot be passed by reference.
    object template = Missing.Value;
    object newTemplate = Missing.Value;
    object documentType = Missing.Value;
    object visible = false;

    Word._Document doc1 = app.Documents.Add(ref template, ref newTemplate, ref documentType, ref visible);
    doc1.Words.First.InsertBefore(p_TextToCheck);
    //Word.ProofreadingErrors spellErrorsColl = doc1.SpellingErrors;
    //errors = spellErrorsColl.Count;

    object optional = Missing.Value;

    doc1.CheckSpelling(
        ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional,
        ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional);

    //label1.Text = errors + " errors corrected ";
    object first = 0;
    object last = doc1.Characters.Count - 1;
    p_TextToCheck.Value = doc1.Range(ref first, ref last).Text;

    object saveChanges = false;
    object originalFormat = Missing.Value;
    object routeDocument = Missing.Value;
    doc1.Close(ref saveChanges, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);
}

object saveChanges1 = false;
object originalFormat1 = Missing.Value;
object routeDocument1 = Missing.Value;

app.Quit(ref saveChanges1, ref originalFormat1, ref routeDocument1);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to reliably (consistent on multiple Office versions) avoid the save dialog is to save the document to a temporary location, close Word, then delete the temporary file.